# Is there a way to use ident authentication with pghero or other workaround?

Tags: postgresql

Installed `pghero` according to the github [docs](https://github.com/ankane/pghero/blob/master/guides/Linux.md#centos--rhel-7) (on CentOS 7), but seeing nothing in web browser (no connection error displayed, but browser is totally blank) and when starting service curl giving response. Looking at the logs I see...

```sh
[root@airflowetl ~]# pghero logs
==> /var/log/pghero/production.log <==
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-01-28 16:21:47 -1000
Processing by PgHero::HomeController#index as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms

PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "airflow"):
...
...
...
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-01-28 23:51:28 -1000
Processing by PgHero::HomeController#index as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "airflow"):
...
...
...
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: pghero-web-1.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Stopped pghero-web-1.service.
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for pghero-web-1.service
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Failed to start pghero-web-1.service.
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Unit pghero-web-1.service entered failed state.
Jan 28 22:59:10 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: pghero-web-1.service failed.
Jan 28 23:09:36 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Stopping pghero-web.service...
Jan 28 23:09:36 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Stopped pghero-web.service.
Jan 28 23:09:36 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Started pghero-web.service.
Jan 28 23:09:36 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Started pghero-web-1.service.
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] Puma starting in cluster mode...
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Version 4.3.0 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Trave
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 16
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Environment: production
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Process workers: 3
Jan 28 23:09:37 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Preloading application
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] ! #<Thread:0x0000561740ea27e0@/opt/pghero/vendor/bundle/ruby
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] - Worker 0 (pid: 12213) booted, phase: 0
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] - Worker 1 (pid: 12215) booted, phase: 0
Jan 28 23:09:38 airflowetl.co.local pghero-web-1.service[12134]: [12134] - Worker 2 (pid: 12219) booted, phase: 0
...
```

and can see the

> 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms

error. Checking the service status, seeing...

```sh
[root@airflowetl ~]# service pghero status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status pghero.service
● pghero.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pghero.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-01-28 23:09:36 HST; 4s ago
 Main PID: 12132 (sleep)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pghero.service
           └─12132 /bin/sleep infinity

Jan 28 23:09:36 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Started pghero.service.
[root@airflowetl ~]# netstat -tulnp | grep 3001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12134/puma 4.3.0 (t
[root@airflowetl ~]# curl -v http://localhost:3001/
* About to connect() to localhost port 3001 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3001 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:3001
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Request-Id: 2bad5f50-438e-4cb3-8e79-41c84eb75c2c
< X-Runtime: 0.017069
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

*No experience with postgresql or db admin stuff*, but [appears](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-unable-to-connect-to-postgresql-779171564.html) that the error is due to the fact that I use `ident` authentication (and appears `pghero` wants to use a password):

```sh
[root@airflowetl ~]# cat /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
...
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

```sh
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)

listen_addresses = '*' # for apache-airflow connection
```

I did this following an [article](https://www.ryanmerlin.com/2019/07/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) of setting up psql as backend for airflow orchestration tool.

Have tried using multiple urls

```sh
sudo pghero config:set DATABASE_URL=postgresql://airflow:xxxx@localhost:5432/airflow
sudo pghero config:set DATABASE_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:xxxx@localhost:5432/airflow
```

but same results.

Not sure how to move forward at this point. Anyone with more experience with `pghero` or postgresql know what could be done here?

Answer (score 0):

> No experience with postgresql or db admin stuff, but appears that the error is due to the fact that I use ident authentication (and appears pghero wants to use a password)

It isn't about what pghero wants.  It is PostgreSQL which is demanding password authentication.

> ```
> host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
> host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
> ```

You are using md5 (i.e. password) on all IPv4 connections (including "localhost"), and using ident on only the IPv6 connection from ::1, which is the IPv6 way of spelling "localhost". pghero is coming in over IPv4, not IPv6, so it is getting commanded to use a password.

You can change the "md5" to "ident" for the 0.0.0.0/0 line (but you probably shouldn't as "ident" is not very secure from outside hosts), or add a line before that one to indicate 127.0.0.1/32 specifically should use ident.  Or change your pghero config to try to connect over IPv6 rather than IPv4.

Your new log file entry shows that it is trying ident and failing at that too.  I don't understand why you are getting both, but they are 7 hours apart so maybe you had changed pg_hba.conf in between.  PostgreSQL will create a more complete report and put it in the PostgreSQL server's log file about why the ident authentication failed.  (It doesn't sent to the complete report to the unauthenticated client, because that would reveal sensitive information).  Find the PostgreSQL server's log file.

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed I posted logs without another piece of info, please see logs again: Am getting *both* password and ident auth errors. Also, if it is using md5, why would I be seeing the `"PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "airflow")"` error?

Comment: I've added a paragraph on the new log entry.  md5 is way of doing password authentication.  In the error message, it just gets called by the generic term.